# InfoPath Repeating Section not displaying dropdown choices in SharePoint

Tags: infopath

I have a repeating section in my InfoPath form that displays a dropdown's choices just fine in the Preview, but after publishing to SharePoint and creating a new list item, only shows the first default choice in subsequent dropdowns after clicking on the add button (for repeated items).

To illustrate, here is the "Preview" of my InfoPath form which seems to be working fine:

[image]

And here is what happens to the dropdown after publishing to my sharepoint list and creating 2 or more repeating items:

[image]

Any explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to resolve this by re-creating that field and re-mapping it while setting its data source to an external list that holds the choices.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer to question:

- [InfoPath drop down field bound to the repeating section it is housed in](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/51364/8319)

starting from the sentence:

> "If you want the same list of choices you could have bound instead to
>   external data source (like, for example, sharepoint list field)"

Comment: I have tried adding an external source to bind to, and it works, but with limitation. While the choices now display as I add repeated items, they only display choices reflecting what was already added to the list, i.e. I want 4 choices to be displayed no matter what: "Year 0, Year 1, Year 2, Year 3", but if the list only contains one item with its year as "Year 3", the dropdown will only show that one choice when I add another item. That could be fixed by a combo box for new values, but there is an additional problem that choices aren't sorted in numerical order and I have no way to sort them.

Comment: I supposed a hackish workaround to this would be to create a separate list just for holding these lookup values, hide that list from any user, and use it for the form lookup to get the "static" number of choices for my dropdown.